# Simulate a constant page size for all viewport sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have a website that has a lot of components which are animated using JavaScript. The website is mainly targeted at users on a desktop. All of the coordinates for the animations, and all of the sizes for the images, depend on the viewport having a width of exactly 1920px (although it could be any height greater than 1000px and it would work). If the viewport is any other width, the images and the animations look like nonsense due to the change in coordinates.

Is there any way I can scale the viewport such that even if it isn't 1920px wide, all of my coordinates and sizes will still be treated as if it is?

I have tried setting `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1920">`, using the CSS `zoom` property, setting `min-width: 1920px` on the `body` element, and setting the browser zoom using JavaScript, all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using "vw" to set the width of your elements?
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp
"vw" is a length unit of 1/100th of the viewport width.

Try using it like this on your css file:

```
.yourelement {
 width: 30vw;
}
```

Comment: I had never heard of this before, thank you very much =). For those passing by, this can be used on images by setting their width in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set your html/body to have a hard width of 1920px in your stylesheet?

```
html, body {
  width: 1920px;
}
```

Comment: This has the same effect as `min-width`. The `body` element simply extends outside of the viewport and part of the page is cropped out.